# Deriving a formula for the coefficients of a power series.

Tags: summation, power-series, rational-functions

[Here is the image containing the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGGk2.png)

> Consider the two  truncated  power  series $u(t)=u_0+u_1x+u_2x^2+u_3x^3+u_4x^4+\cdots+u_nx^n$ and $d(t)=d+d_1x+d_2x^2+d_3x^3+d_4x^4+\cdots+dx^n$.  Show  how to derive  the     formula
>   \begin{align*}
> q_i=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}q_kd_{i-k}}{d_0}
> \end{align*}
>   where  the $q_i$ are  the coefficients  of the truncated  power series for $q(t)=\frac{u(t)}{d(t)}$.

I have tried rearranging and rewriting and many other things. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question doesn't look correct.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JackyChong I thought the same thing. There may be a typo or poorly worded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Hint:** The statement of this problem shows some serious flaws.
>
> - $u(t)=u_0+u_1x+u_2x^2+u_3x^3+u_4x^4+\cdots+u_nx^n$:  The left-hand side indicates a function in $t$ while the right-hand side indicates a function in $x$.
> - $d(t)=d+d_1x+d_2x^2+d_3x^3+d_4x^4+\cdots+dx^n$: The same flaw as above. Additionally, the first and last coefficient are $d$ but should presumably be $d\color{blue}{_0}$  and  $d\color{blue}{_n}$ which  are *different*  values in general.
> - $q_i=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}q_kd_{i-k}}{d_0}$:  The range of $i$  is missing here. The formula for $q_i$ seems to be incorrect.

Usually we would make the  approach

\begin{align*}
q(x)=q_0+q_1x+q_2x^2\cdots+q_nx^n=\frac{u(x)}{d(x)}
\end{align*}
from which we derive
\begin{align*}
&u_0+u_1x+u_2x^2+\cdots+u_nx^n\\
&\qquad=(q_0+q_1x+q_2x^2+\cdots+q_nx^n)(d_0+d_1x+d_2x^2+\cdots d_nx^n)
\end{align*}
We now compare terms with equal powers, analyse
\begin{align*}
u_0&=q_0d_0\\
u_1&=q_0d_1+q_1d_0\\
u_2&=q_0d_2+q_1d_1+q_2d_0\\
&\vdots\\
u_n&=q_0d_n+q_1d_{n-1}+\cdots+q_nd_0
\end{align*}
from which another formula follows.

Comment: thanks so much for your clear response! this is what I was working with earlier, but of course I could not interpret the summation and the rest of the question. So my first question is that wont this return an equation for the coefficients of u(x)? and not q(x)?

Comment: or perhaps this may have been what was meant to be asked in the original question?

Comment: @Numnumberry: You're welcome. Here we assume $u(x)$ and $d(x)$ to be known and want to calculate the coefficients of $q(x)$. This can be done by *rearranging* the chain of equalities in my hint. Starting with $q_0=\frac{u_0}{d_0}, q_1=\frac{u_1}{d_0}-\frac{1}{d_0}\left(q_0\right),q_2=\frac{u_2}{d_0}-\frac{1}{d_0}\left(q_0d_2+q_1d_1\right)$, etc. Note that we also need $d_0\ne 0$ which should be clearly stated in the problem.

Comment: yeah I see, looking at this now it seems to be matching what was intended (for there is a dsub0 consistent in the denominator for every coefficient of q and there is a somewhat matching relationship for the summation in the numerator.. of course, I say somewhat because of the initial issues with the problem). THANKS

Comment: @Numnumberry: You're welcome! :-)